# Scrollview is behind ActionBar Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, scrollview

How do I prevent the ScrollView from going behind the ActionBar? I want the top of the text to be just beneath the ActionBar.

[image]

Comment: please post your manifest file, you might be using a certain theme

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this to your ScrollView xml

```
android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

Comment: Thank you :) I was hard coding the values.

Answer (score 5):

If you have `android:layout_gravity="center"`on your ScrollView or bellow, you can try to remove it

Comment: This is THE answer!